# Colpitts not oscillating as expected

Tags: oscillator

I have tried to mount a Colpitts oscillator twice and its oscillation is not the expected. I get like 13 MHz oscillation when expected 50MHz using the following schematic:

[image: Colpitts Oscillator used]

When I change the Inductor value it doesn't appear to change. That's why I thought it could be an effect of the parasitic capacitances, as I'm using the following board to mount it: ´

[image: Board used (don't really know the name of it)]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for asking it here :) So, from what to what do you change the inductor value? And: yes, these parallel, long lines will have parasitic capacitance and parasitic inductance.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for guiding me! I changed the Inductor value from 0.15uH to 22uH. That would mean the expected frequency would be ~5MHz. It really worked with those values and the oscillation obtained was the expected.

I have also tried changing the Capacitor and Inductor values to 
greater ones (which result in lower oscillating frequency) and the circuit works fine. I honestly don't remember which values I put as I was just testing the behaviour of the circuit when I used greater or smaller values.

Comment: What I really found is that the frequency didn't get greater than 13MHz, even if I used the values to obtain a 50MHz wave.

Comment: Aha! so, yeah, maybe [your transistor](http://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/reference/2N2222A.pdf) is simply too slow? Or has too much in- and output capacitance? Can you check the datasheet above(I'm running out of time)?

Comment: You can **forget** about using such a prototype PCB to do 50 MHz circuits. Get one with small islands instead of long tracks and if you make everything **as small as possible** with **short connections** you might achieve 50 MHz. But really that requires **experience**.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The Input and Output capacitances are 25 and 8pF. About checking the speed of the transistor, I don't really know how to know it..

Comment: @FakeMoustache I don't have much experience but I for sure I can try to mount it. What would you recomend? From the oscillators I have studied, I think this is the most appropiate to use when 50MHz are needed, although the values for the capacitors and inductors are relatively low...

Comment: well, these values definitely are in the same order of magnitude as the capacitance between two adjacent stripboard lines... so, yeah, 50 MHz is really not something I'd do on stripboard (also, not really on perfboard, either, but then you start to run out of prototyping board options… I'd probably try with a board of SMD components that I'd solder to a $3 board ordered from oshpark.com, but these take 2 or 3 weeks to show up at my door, usually, since I'm not in the US)

Comment: Are you sure you can reach 50 Mhz with a 2n2222? Seems as bit sluggish for this kind of things. IIRC, its storage time is about 200 ns.

Comment: Storage time is irrelevant as the transistor is not used for on/off switching. The 2n2222 has an Ft of 250 MHz, not that fast but should be sufficient. The problem is really not the transistor but the way you build the circuit up. All the parasitic capacitance and inductance of the wires limits the frequency you can reach and 50 MHz at the limit even if you do everything in an optimal way.

Comment: @FakeMoustache But I am using the right oscillator circuit right? There are other setups, but I think that for my frequencies Colpitts is the most appropiate. Could be a solution mounting it to a PCB? At least to ensure the parasitics are minimized...

Comment: I see no power supply bypass capacitor in your schematic. This circuit **requires** a low-impedance path from the top end of L1 to the bottom end of C2. Add a 0.1uF capacitor having *very short lead-length*.

Comment: Hope you got youre answer.
But How did you calculated the output frequency? I actually Don't know that.

Answer (score 1):

The resonant circuit includes the Power Supply. You must bypass that. Your SPICE simulation VDD source has ZERO impedance; on your protoboard, that battery or power supply are located some distance away from the transistor, and those long wires ---- 100 nanoHenry per 100 millimeter ---- cause Fresonant to be much lower than expected.

Again, place a 0.01UF cap with SHORT LEADS from top of L1 to GND.

Alter your layout so those leads are, in total, only 1cm long.

In a final circuit, use a Ground Plane, further reducing the VDD inductance.

EDIT The actual frequency of oscillation is 1/4 of the predicted 50MHz. That means the actual inductance is 4*4 = 16X higher than what is simulated. 16x 0.15uH is 2.13uH............which is about 2 meters of wire.

At low frequencies, the 2N2222 may perform well. But at 50MHz?

Comment: I will try to do what you recommend and will post the results. Thank you. I don't know if that is what you meant but, for sure I don't have 2 meters of wire in my circuit. About the transistor used, I am really not sure. Should I look for another with a greater Ft?

Comment: Hi, I have found that the inductances values i'm using are wrong ones. I'm using an LCR Meter and a 0.1uH inductor is 1.2uH when measured. I have checked other inductor values and it doesn't appear to get greater. I'm getting a 17MHz oscillation as much now. What would you recommend to get reliable inductor values? I think capacitors are not a problem in the circuit, as the measured values are correct.

Comment: You can just wind your own inductor. Just get some magnet wire, maybe 22 AWG or 24 AWG should be good. There's calculators on the web to figure out how many turns you need for a certain inductance. Wind around the base of a drill bit so you can get accurate diameter. Take look at https://www.eeweb.com/toolbox/coil-inductance

Comment: You need some decent Q (low loss inductos and capacitors) and a transistor capable of injecting energy into the tank from the emitter at 50MHz. Phase shifts out near Ftau may prevent satisfying the Barkhausen Criteria for oscillation.

Answer (score 0):

2N2222 has a ft of 300MHz min. He is fine for this job.
BUT: The the two 100pF-capacitors are way to large. Try 4.7pF or maybe even smaller. The 100pF have such a low reactance at 50 MHz, C1 virtually creates a shortcut between emitter and collector of the transistor.

Oh, I forgot: As someone else told You, a pcb with separate solder points for each hole is better for building RF electronics. And yes, You should better place a 100µF capacitor (bigger is no problem) between plus and minus.

Comment: It is not true that the 100pF capacitors are shorts at 50MHz. In fact, they have a reactance of roughly 32 ohms. The two 100pF caps are part of the feedback network with the inductor. The oscillation frequency should be roughly 1/(2pi*sqrt(LC)) where L is the inductance And C is the two 100pF in series (ie 50pF). Also, you should definitely NOT use a 100uF capacitor for decoupling the DC supply from this circuit. A 100uF cap will most likely haven't a self resonant frequency below 50MHZ making it useless for this circuit. Perhaps a better idea is a parallel combination of multiple sized caps.