# Simple oscillator design not working when implemented

Tags: circuit-design, oscillator

I thought this would be a quick build, but maybe there is something wrong with the design. Even though no waveform occurs, the MOSFET gets very hot.

[image]

f = 1/(2π√[C(L1+L2)])

An n-channel [2N7000](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/2N7000-D-33553.pdf) MOSFET was chosen with the Hartly configuration to make a 160 kHz oscillator with an output power greater than 16 dBm (or 0.0398 W).

The tank circuit has L1 = L2 = 50 nH and C = 10uF.

Find choke:

\$A_V = g_mR_D\$

\$A_V = (2\sqrt{K_nI_d})(L_D2\pi*f)\$

\$10 = (2\sqrt{4*0.002})(56*10^{-6}2\pi*160000)\$

\$L_D = 56uH = L_3\$

Find Cc:

\$160k = 1/(2\pi*L_{3}C_{c})\$

\$C_{c} = 18uF\$

Find R1:

\$Let: V_{GS} = 2\$

\$10=RI_D + V_{GS}\$

R = 4kΩ

Should I redesign something? Should I add a buffer stage of some sort?

Should I just start the implementation from scratch again? Should I give up on trying to use a FET for this application? Why?

---

I also swapped it out the Hartley tank with Colpitts, but the signal rapidly attenuated within seconds. If I said that correctly:

[image]

---

I also looked at the others, but they all use BJTs. I really wanted to use a MOSFET to be unique.

- This one isn't really about my situation: [AC analysis of a oscillator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/370464/ac-analysis-of-a-oscillator)
- My choke is bigger, but their's is for higher frequency: [Colpitts not oscillating as expected](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/300637/colpitts-not-oscillating-as-expected?rq=1)

Comment: On a quick look, I doubt that you have any gain with that 10 ohm load in there. I would try removing it and see if you get any oscillation at all.

Comment: 50 nanoHenry inductors seen low, for 160KHz operating frequency. Given 1uH at 1MHz is =J6.3 ohms, and 1uH at 160KHz is +j1 ohm, the 50nH inductors are 0.05 ohms.

Comment: It gets hot because M1 is being turned on fairly hard - your biasing sets 5 volts on the gate and this is enough to drag an amp or two through most commonly used MOSFETs. Try using a 10 ohm source resistor.

Comment: I increased the inductance, and it works without the load. Although, with the load, it continues to attenuate to hell--and distortion is through the roof. I think I should somehow make an emitter-follower...somewhere.